# AES key size in Java

Tags: java, encryption, aes

Testing RSA to encrypt an AES key, I [realized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579103/too-much-data-for-rsa-block-fail-what-is-pkcs7) that RSA has only 1 block with a limited size (settable by the programmer) do store the encrypted key.
The question is, when I use:

```
KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey()
```

the AES keys will have a constant size in every computer and jvm implementation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an init method in the KeyGenerator that allows you to specify the number of bits.

```
KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGenerator.init(128);
SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
```

Will that do what you need?

The default [appears](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/crypto/provider/AESKeyGenerator.java.html) to be 128 bits, but I would not assume that all JVM's use the same default, or that it will always be the default.

Comment: I agree on not depending on the default value.  (Other Java default values change over time.)  Also, it is worth noting that the only valid values are 128, 192 or 256 bits for `.init()`, and that 192 and 256 might not even be available...which could lead to some painful deployment fun.

Answer (score 2):

[Suns Java Cryptography Extension documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#AppA) states that multiple key sizes are supported for AES keys and doesn't provide any information on the default size.

The maximum size of keys can also vary depending on the jurisdictional files used by different versions of Suns JVM.

Comment: this is bad.. so I can't just set a size and beleave it will work fine everywhere..

Comment: the size can also be limited depending on the jurisdictional settings.

Comment: it looks like the AES can be always 128 bits (16 bytes)

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html

Every implementation of the Java platform is required to support the following standard Cipher transformations with the keysizes in parentheses:

```
AES/CBC/NoPadding (128)
AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding (128)
AES/ECB/NoPadding (128)
AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding (128)
DES/CBC/NoPadding (56)
DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding (56)
DES/ECB/NoPadding (56)
DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding (56)
DESede/CBC/NoPadding (168)
DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding (168)
DESede/ECB/NoPadding (168)
DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding (168)
RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding (1024, 2048)
RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding (1024, 2048)
RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding (1024, 2048)
```

Answer (score 0):

`KeyGenerator` has several `init()` methods; you should call one of them before generating a key. The Javadoc for `KeyGenerator` specifies that in case you do not call one of the `init()` method, then "each provider must supply (and document) a default initialization."

So this is provider-specific. Since you initialize the key generator with the "AES" algorithm name, one may assume that you will get a key with a size suitable for AES, i.e. 128, 192 or 256 bits (16, 24 and 32 bytes, respectively). But which one you get is up to the actual provider, which may depend upon the JVM and possibly its configuration.