# Decode using cipher Algorithm

Tags: java, web-services

Here is a list of components present in private key

```
modulus: 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
public exponent: 10001
private exponent: 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
primeP: d98204decf9a6354e63297ff181e67554b310198a9fedce5b45018e21c3a3496481c3641eb654701d7272cf003c9c3dc3be7cc5de7792805dfb93fab86bf39c0c2237068efe09346e8a84795ff27eff25356715dbc60828ef2fd1988a49e0854ccbc2fd66f7bb8a37718ca46c6931fb65c571d706b5f0974477780138274dc21
primeQ: d3891c8dbd0b71b5ab06f0ce6387f2c0f03099814f7133632d79c705d45b2b8dcc82e0d667634d86570feed203bcddbb57e16fc5198f7d1c0811313e4c34e061022bb83971ede0a9d89fb786f164fe01842b9c158c547e3ae308ed0111ad2e3474cfb514739f2ee0db2d2a4162c89aa6df4511b8afaee8bd8d006a4a3f719dc9
primeExponentP: 28d783369b60f019f707b506cf6e9614ac03cdbaeee0ce75cb7fe6cc3e64a78f388723a10924814ad52da400859593537d642f39cac7333eb71dbfd8e37a70cbc32888690bf1ed75b926301af8487583d926382f53ba0389f8129282d7f65cb61fa38e90036b05e69bec69bf147677d3f44edf5646b317c15fd20e989b3c7a41
primeExponentQ: 4cb28009dc2b54153c678dd4273e59841f125ff604a9d4a9f7091a6240b6b5b9fa16d212aaf5d45c0b2119c447daa8c28e808c97f84690642380a84c203163d18889f587ce89235631d6e72224502bd0bced5af06d2b0d81a863ca1b031fb98b07776ffe74559917aa205c1bcd07531b8204770271a0877e82ab4dde91d64e11
crtCoefficient: 82cee4d829988a09694b598e08065e38fbf221f12fb1fbc3ab564d9d7eaad1e39402607f176d0c6c9f9afa5d10e2e441a65f2cac8e13f67e1c86a67cfb805f15df84d52bdea51acd2e4ea4444b6a3ba2bd22667cb494062209cb9c17efdb6d6c34e460dc59cd9b8a3f2d941c2a954c9c827891ae6ac5af6f98f8b9532b8cf14e
```

i decode that string with this private key by using cipher algorithm but the problem is i got an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: too much data for RSA block
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCERSACipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
```

Anybody know why i got that exception and how can i resolve that

**Edit:**
 Private key has 8 blocks of data but public key have only one block that is modulus
 public key is used to encrypt the data 
 private key is used to decrypt the data but private key has 8 blocks of data
 i have a question i need to use only modulus block to decrypt the data

Comment: May be duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579103/too-much-data-for-rsa-block-fail-what-is-pkcs7

Comment: @CarlSaldanha when i did PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey(pvtKeyFileName);
    logger.info("Private Key : " + privateKey.getFormat());
i got PCKS#8